# Python - assigning categories based on value range

Tags: python, categories

**Solved**

I am trying to figure out why my solution is wrong. Made both, second is correct. I like the first better, because the intervals are more manageable and pleasing for my bad programming brain. And quite frankly, I am kind of lost as to what happens from pH 8 (Neutral) and up (solution 2). Therefore I would like to continue to work in this style for future assignment, rather than solution 2 (correct). However, solution 1 that I prefer is wrong and returns **weakly** though it should be **strongly acidic** Why is that and how can this be fixed?

Def: assigning category based on pH (2.3)

**pH & category** 
0–2 Strongly acidic 
3–5 Weakly acidic 
6–8 Neutral 
9–11 Weakly basic 
12–14 Strongly basic 
Anything else falls in **pH out of range**

```
def pH2Category(pH):
    if pH < 0 or pH > 14:
        category = "pH out of range"
    elif (pH >=0) and (pH < 3):
        category = "Strongly acidic"
    elif (pH >=3) and (pH < 6):
        category = "Weakly acidic"
    elif  (pH >=5) and (pH < 9):
        category = "Neutral"
    elif (pH >=9) and (pH < 12):
        category = "Weakly basic"
    else:
        category = "Strongly basic"
    return category
    print(pH2Category(2.3))

def pH2Category(pH):
    if pH < 0 or pH > 14:
        category = "pH out of range"
    elif pH < 3:
        category = "Strongly acidic"
    elif pH < 6:
        category = "Weakly acidic"
    elif pH <= 8:
        category = "Neutral"
    elif pH <= 11:
        category = "Weakly basic"
    else:
        category = "Strongly basic"
    return category
print(pH2Category(2.3))
```

Comment: Indentation.  You have the `return` statement indented so it only takes effect in the `else` clause.  Shift it out one tab and all will be well.

Comment: ^ A mistake on my behalf when typing. Just fixed it, however the issue remains

Comment: you also have an overlapping range from ph 5 to ph 6. I will post an answet for you in a sec

Comment: @Ailah, just sent you an answer that follows the pattern you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to a pattern similar to what you know, the following should work:

```
def pH2Category(pH):
    if pH < 0 or pH > 14:
        return "pH out of range"
    elif (pH >= 0) and (pH < 3):
        return "Strongly acidic"
    elif (pH >= 3) and (pH < 6):
        return "Weakly acidic"
    elif  (pH >= 6) and (pH < 9):
        return "Neutral"
    elif (pH >= 9) and (pH < 12):
        return "Weakly basic"
    else:
        return "Strongly basic"

    print(pH2Category(2.3))
```

Please note the above will a) return 'pH out of range', so if you only want that printed and not returned, replace `return` in the first if with a `print` statement, and b) you had overlapping ranges in 5-6 as @quqa mentioned in the comment, so I fixed that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. After working with this later I came up with the same solution. I test in CodeJudge but it is still not correct. Something goes wrong in weakly basic part, where the output should be strongly basic instead. (E.g. when printing pH 11.1, according to the CodeJudge feedback)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you did but here is one that can help you start with python and make your life easier

```
# dictionary of (min_value, max_value): 'Description of Ph'
# just fill out for your needs
table = {
    (0, 3): 'Strongly Acidic',
    (3, 6): 'Wakly Acidic',
    (6, 9): 'Neutral',
    ...
}

def check_ph(ph):
    
    for ph_range, ph_description in table.items():
        # for every pair that you see in table
        if ph_range[0] <= ph < ph_range[1]:
            # if ph is greater or eqaual than min_value
            # and lesser than max_value
            print(ph_description)
            # return the ph description
            return ph_description
    
    # if the value is outside the table range just print it out
    print('ph out of range')
```

Comment: I was hoping for something similar to what I proposed. As I get confused easily and like to stick to things that I know. But it seems like an over all good structure and I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that is scalable you should consider a Segment Tree (log-speed lookups).

Doing wasteful comparisons is cheap for something with only a few categories, but even with your 5 categories you could be doing 10 comparisons when 3-4 would do.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree

Comment: This seems interesting but how do you apply it to answer OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in `portion`, a library I wrote that provides structure and operations for intervals. It's distributed on PyPI, so you can easily install it with `pip install portion`.

Among other, it provides an `IntervalDict` class that acts like a Python `dict` but accepts ranges as keys.

Applied on your example:

```py
>>> import portion as P
>>> d = P.IntervalDict()
>>> d[P.open(-P.inf, P.inf)] = 'pH out of range'
>>> d[P.closed(0, 2)] = 'Strongly acidic'
>>> d[P.closed(3, 5)] = 'Weakly acidic'
>>> ...
>>> d[1]
'Strongly acidic'
>>> d[300]
'pH out of range'
```